# What are the components symbolized in these 4 highlighted areas of this schematic?

Tags: gas-sensor

I am a beginner and I understand only the most basic portions of this schematic. Could someone smarter please help me understand the highlighted areas?

[image: Image Source: Zhengzhou Winsen Electronics Technology Co.,Ltd]
**Source:** Schematic was copied from page 4 of the manufacturer's product [datasheet](https://www.winsen-sensor.com/d/files/PDF/Electrochemical%20Gas%20Sensor/7-series%20Electrochemical/ME4-H2S%200-100ppm(Ver1.2)%20-%20Manual.pdf).
***Zhengzhou Winsen Electronics Technology Co.,Ltd***

The circuit design is for a gas detection sensor element. As various levels of the gas being detected is sensed the output voltage should vary on one of the pins. Unfortunately I need this design converted to a PCB that the sensor element plugs into. I have the circuit half done, but the highlighted areas I am confused about.

I will likely have a couple follow up questions because as I said I want to understand this circuit, not just get an answer. For example, the block at the top middle, is that a voltage divide circuit? Thanks everyone. :)

Comment: Welcome and nice to meet you. Ah, let me see. A year ago I played with cheapy gas sensors. My goal was to ***UNDERSTAND*** how the sensors work. I also did some experiments, and finally made a ***reading/experiment log***. (1) https://penzu.com/public/4adb0a63. You might like to skim it to get a rough idea of the basic things. You might like to let me know your electronics knowledge and skills (Note 1), before I try to explain the circuit. ***Note 1***. How much do you know about (a) Operational amplifier, (b)  MOSFET, (c) CO, and CO2 etc, (d) Do you know how to blink a LED using Arduino？

Comment: You might also like to read my post on understanding and playing with a CO sensor. You might also find some references to understand gas sensors: ***How Can Rpi3B+ read MQ9 Gas Sensor?*** - Rpi SE 2019Oct30
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105116/how-can-rpi3b-read-mq9-gas-sensor/105219#105219. Happy learning and understanding. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J177 P-channel JFET

R3 resistor 20K

RT1 thermistor 10K at 25°C

U1A/U1B the halves of a dual op-amp

R3,RT1,R5 form a temperature-dependent resistance to help temperature compensate the gas sensor output.

You should credit Zhengzhou Winsen with the graphic you copied.

Comment: Awesome! Sorry for not giving credit to the schematic, Winsen hopefully will be the supplier to the elements needed. I will edit the post to give the credit. It makes so much more sense now, especially with how sensitive to climate I have found these sensors to be. Thank you.

Could you please explain in more detail what a dual op-amp is, how it might be used in other applications? Again great answer.

Comment: @JaeNulton Look up the part number. Read the datasheet. Look up op-amps on Wikipedia. "What is an op-amp?" is far too broad a question.

Comment: Will do Spehro, again thank you.

@tlfong01 your documentation is incredible. You have given me far more insight than the sensor manufacturer. I have read it twice and will be printing to use as a guide. Hopefully I can keep notes as good as you have! To answer your questions, I know nothing of operational amplifiers but will be studying up tonight. As far as MOSFET, I have only used them when directed to and stuck closely to instruction, I only know the base theory of some of their applications. The gasses - moderate knowledge. I have done dozens of projects with various PLC's and SBC's.