# Seeking deeper understand of reading a schematic with an op-amp IC (AD-8574)

Tags: operational-amplifier, schematics, gas-sensor

A couple days ago I was seeking some education on [reading a schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/528922/what-are-the-components-symbolized-in-these-4-highlighted-areas-of-this-schemati), I had great answers for replies and I feel like I am closer. What I am trying to get my head around is the use of a dual channel op-amp circuit. I think the circuit shown below is indicating the exact part number I need to use, as well as the pins I would use from the IC itself.
[image]
**Source:** Schematic was copied from page 4 of the manufacturer's product [datasheet](https://www.winsen-sensor.com/d/files/PDF/Electrochemical%20Gas%20Sensor/7-series%20Electrochemical/ME4-H2S%200-100ppm(Ver1.2)%20-%20Manual.pdf).
***Zhengzhou Winsen Electronics Technology Co.,Ltd***

Looking at the part number's datasheet (the source of the below pin out diagram as taken from [Mouser.com](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/ad8574-ep-1517459.pdf)) it looks like I would just need one of these chips on the board, is that correct?

[image]

Is that IC in the pinout a quad channel operational amplifier? And last question, in the schematic above, is the schematic indicating the actual pin numbers to run the traces to? Seems like a clearly defined blueprint of what exactly I should be doing or am I just being overly optimistic?

Comment: The schematic says AD8572 and the pinout says AD8574. *That's a different chip*. The pins on an AD8572 are (probably) different from the pins on an AD8574. So you can't use the schematic pin numbers on an AD8574.

Comment: The 8572 is probably the dual version, which will explain the difference in power pins. Look at its datasheet (from Analog Devices) and compare with the 8574.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that IC in the pinout a quad channel operational amplifier?

[image]

*Figure 1. It's written so big that you missed it!*

Yes. It's a quad amplifier.

> ... is the schematic indicating the actual pin numbers to run the traces to?

Yes.

> Seems like a clearly defined blueprint of what exactly I should be doing or am I just being overly optimistic?

The schematic shows the *schema* and good one's make it clear what each section is supposed to do. At high frequency layout becomes important as stray capacitance and inductance can affect the signals. This circuit will probably run fine on breadboard or prototyping board if you're running, say, at audio frequencies or less.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the confirmation, accepted as answer. I feel a little silly for having missed the IC's name, I just looked at the pins on that datasheet. Too much coffee. :) It seems that with good schematics, basic projects can be quite simple.

Comment: I didn't read through the datasheet but watch out for different packaging options (surface mount rather than 0.1" pitch package) which may have different pinouts. It's unlikely in this case but worth checking and worth checking that you're ordering the right part.